# How can I update a TList while iterating with a for-in loop?

Tags: delphi, for-loop

I am trying to learn about Generics in Delphi but have a very basic problem with TList.

I have successfully created a list integers and filled it with 1000 odd numbers.  I want to change every number on the list that is divisible by 3 to 0.  I thought that I could do something like this.

```
For I in Mylist Do
Begin
  If (I mod 3)= 0 Then
    I:=0;
End;
```

This clearly does not work so I would appreciate someone explaining what will.

Comment: This is one area where the Delphi language is really weak. Other languages have powerful iterators that allow you to mutate the collections.

Comment: I wonder how much work it would take for Embarcadero to let an enumerator's `Current` property be read/write instead of read-only.

Comment: Possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/q/1105519/960757, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2246087/960757.

Comment: See also how to [Increment an integer variable in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16326975/576719).

Comment: I'm thinking of D here: `foreach (ref int value; collection) value++;`

Answer (score 9):

You are using a `for..in` loop, which uses a read-only enumerator.  This code:

```
For I in Mylist Do
Begin
  If (I mod 3) = 0 Then
    I := 0;
End;
```

Is actually doing this:

```
Enum := Mylist.GetEnumerator;
while Enum.MoveNext do
Begin
  I := Enum.Current;
  If (I mod 3) = 0 Then
    I := 0;
End;
```

That is why you cannot modify the list contents in a `for..in` loop.  You have to use an older-style `for` loop instead, using the `TList<T>.Items[]` property to access the values:

```
For I := 0 to Mylist.Count-1 Do
Begin
  If (Mylist[I] mod 3) = 0 Then
    Mylist[I] := 0;
End;
```

**Update**: to then remove the zeros, you can do this:

```
For I := Mylist.Count-1 downto 0 Do
Begin
  If Mylist[I] = 0 Then
    Mylist.Delete(I);
End;
```

Or, do it in the initial loop so you don't need a second loop:

```
For I := Mylist.Count-1 downto 0 Do
Begin
  If (Mylist[I] mod 3) = 0 Then
    Mylist.Delete(I);
End;
```

Comment: Many thanks - that was very helpful and I have modified my code successfully.  However, this raises a further question.  How would I go about removing all items from the list that are now zero? (and, of course, effectively shorten the list).

Comment: You would have to loop through the list (backwards) a second time looking for zeros.  I updated my answer with examples.

Answer (score 4):

Your code won't work because you're trying to modify the loop control variable (`I`) in the loop, which isn't allowed. It tells you that in the compiler error:

```
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(23): E2081 Assignment to FOR-Loop variable 'i'
```

If you want to modify the list, you need to iterate through the list the old-fashioned way (by index) instead.

```
for i := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
  if (List[i] mod 3) = 0 then
    List[i] := 0;
```

Comment: Yes, but I would add: "If you want to modify the list, you need to iterate through the list the old-fashioned way (by index) rather than by enumerator (note that there are no iterators in Delphi's collections)."

Comment: @Rudy There are iterators. They are just badly named as enumerators.

Comment: @Rudy: I agree that I should have clarified with the "modify the list" addition. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Iteration_Over_Containers_Using_For_statements) refers to `forin` as iteration and not enumeration, though. I've rephrased the sentence somewhat.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Iterators generally allow you to modify the collection underneath. Enumerators generally don't. Delphi's collections have enumerators, and the for-in loop builds on those. You can't modify the collection using these enumerators.

Comment: FWIW: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948194/difference-between-java-enumeration-and-iterator. That is just one example.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis You are talking about language specific terminology, in the case you link to Java. A for in loop does not need to iterate over every single item. Ergo enumeration is the wrong term. The fact that lots of other people have made this mistake in terminology does not make it not be a mistake.

Comment: Here is [`one for C#`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/716238/960757). I also don't see any mistake. They just designed the language and call *that thing* enumerator.

Comment: @Rudy It is a mistake, in my opinion, to call these things enumerators because they do not enumerate. Enumeration would result in every member of the collection being yielded. The thing is that every language designer has a subtly different view on the terminology. So given that there are so many different meanings, I don't think you are in any position to tell Ken that his use of terminology is wrong. Likewise I cannot tell you that either. There is no single right and wrong naming here.

Comment: @TLama C++ has no enumerators. It has iterators. That can be read only or read/write, amongst other things. So the original claimed distinction is clearly not so. And before you say, we are not talking about C++, we aren't talking about Delphi either because it has no read/write iterators/enumerators.

Comment: I don't see why enumeration should result in every member.

Comment: @Rudy I hope you don't feel this way when enumerating teeth! ;-)

Comment: @David: That's an enumeration, not an enumerator.

Comment: @Rudy and what does an enumerator do then?

Comment: @David: if I enumerate teeth, I am examining them. That is not a modification. I then write down the numbers of the teeth that need modification or removal. ;-)

Comment: An enumerator, well, enumerates. An enumeration is the result of the completion of this action.

Comment: @Rudy This really makes my point then. The end result of a delphi enumerator's work need not be an enumeration.

Comment: Ok, then an enumerator does not have to result in an enumeration. An enumeration can be constructed using an enumerator, though. <g>

Comment: @Rudy Anyway, all I'm saying is that I think Ken was fine to use  the term iterator.

Comment: @Rudy: As I mentioned before, the Delphi Language Guide says that `forin` does an iteration. (See the link from my prior comment.)

Comment: @Ken: the Delphi Language Guide sometimes uses its own terms and may contain errors. The fact that the RTL uses GetEnumerator, etc. seems to tell me it enumerates. <g>

Comment: @Rudy In your head, iterate means that the items can be modified. Enumerate means that the items cannot be modified. You are welcome to use those meanings if you wish. But don't kid yourself that these meanings are universally accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  _List: TList<integer>;
  i: integer;
begin
  _List := TList<integer>.Create;
  try

    // Add few odd numbers
    for i := 0 to 100 do
    begin
      if (i mod 2) <> 0 then
        _List.Add(i);
    end;

    // Replace numbers with 0 that divides by 3
    for i := 0 to _List.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if (_List[i] mod 3) = 0 then
        _List[i] := 0;
    end;

    // Show new list
    for i := 0 to _List.Count - 1 do
      OutputDebugstring(PWideChar(IntToStr(_List[i])));

  finally
    FreeAndNil(_List);
  end;
end;
```

You do not change iteration itself (e.g. i), you want to change value (e.g. _List[i])

Comment: _List is a local variable, which is not accessible from anywhere else. Why do you FreeAndNil it?

Comment: I didn't say it was wrong. I am just asking why you do it. The variable is at the very end of its scope and not accessible from anywhere else, so I wondered why you use `FreeAndNil` instead of `.Free`.